# how to format sql result using batch script

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I am writing batch script to connect different databases and execute same SQL script for each database.
I want output as :

```
"db_name1","Query_result: "xyz"
"db_name2","Query_result: abc"
"db_name3","Query_result: lmn"
```

but now in `Query_result` - all stuff after spool, even the sql query also get appended to the result.
I just simply want to display database name in 1st and query result in 2nd column. 2nd column may have multiple rows or columns to display result i.e. suppose Query_result contains multiple user names then each name should be in different row.

here is my batch script

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (InstallList.txt) do (
echo "DB_NAME : %%a"," 
echo.
echo QUERY_RESULT :
echo.
sqlplus %%b < mysql.sql 
echo "
echo.
) >> result.csv
pause;
```

In InstallList.txt

```
dbname1=username/password
dbname2=username/password
dbname3=username/password
```

And mysql.sql is

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
SET LINES 32000
SET TERMOUT OFF ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
spool &1
select user_name from employee where designation= 'manager';
spool off
exit
```

Please help me as early as possible.
thank you.

Comment: What does your output currently look like?

Comment: Currently in my output, all stuff like connected to database then query, result n then disconnected from database all such messages are included.

Comment: please check question once again i have made some changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-S` option to sqlplus, so that it doesn't print the `connected to` etc.

`sqlplus -h` (help mode) shows, under `-S`:

```
-S             Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
               the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
               commands.
```

So, your command becomes

```
sqlplus -S %%b < mysql.sql
```

instead of

```
sqlplus %%b < mysql.sql
```

Comment: m sorrry rene i made some changes & also add -s it works thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

May be [`SET VERIFY OFF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699432) and/or [`SET FEEDBACK OFF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2698970) helps:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
SET LINES 32000
SET TERMOUT OFF ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
...
```

Check [this site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm) for more.

***p.s.***: added as per question in the comment.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (InstallList.txt) do (
sqlplus %%bb @mysql.sql result.csv %%a
)
pause;
```

So just loop through entries and  start the SQL script with file name and DB name as parameters.

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1

SET LINES 32000
SET TERMOUT OFF 
SET NEWPAGE 0 
SET PAGESIZE 0 
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
SET HEADING OFF 
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON

SPOOL &1 APPEND

SELECT '"DB_NAME: &2"' || ',' || '"Query result: ' || user_name || '"'
  FROM employee 
 WHERE designation= 'manager';

SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
```

Use `append` to add rows, and the second parameter to concatenate the DB name. Note that this piece of code is untested but the basic idea is working pretty well.

***p.p.s.***: output of above is for instance

```
"DB_NAME: DB1","Query result: Tom Scott"
"DB_NAME: DB2","Query result: Liza Medison"
"DB_NAME: DB3","Query result: Eric Brandon"
"DB_NAME: DB4","Query result: Sam Smith"
"DB_NAME: DB5","Query result: Paula Winter"
```

Comment: spool routes the output into a file and the first parameter (`&1`) is the file name. You can create a new file or append to an existing (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm). `&1` itself is the first parameter that is passed into the script (check _Passing Parameters...._ at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#CACIIEDF)

Comment: Looking at your batch script, I could think there is still one problem: spool in `sqlplus %%b < mysql.sql` can append the output  to the file; however, the batch script itself opened the file already. So let me suggest a small change ...

Comment: You can format the rows as you like. I made a small adjustment, so the output is similar to what you had in your question. `TRIMSPOOL ON` removes trailing spaces, what looks much better in case of a line size of 32000 characters ;)